# Make sure int variable is 2 digits long, else add 0 in front to make it 2 digits long

Tags: linux, bash, shell, integer

How do I check a int variable ($inputNo) to see if it’s 2 or more decimal digits long?

Example:

```
inputNo="5"
```

Should be changed to: 05

```
inputNo="102"
```

Should be left alone: 102

I thought about using `wc` and `if` statements, but `wc -m` doesn’t seems to give the actual characters passed into `wc`, as `wc` always seems to give +1 to the characters that is given.

But I don’t know how to add a 0 in front of the current input number.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the bash-builtin `printf` with the `-v` option to write it to a variable rather than print it to standard output:

```
pax> inputNo=5   ; printf -v inputNo "%02d" $inputNo ; echo $inputNo
05
pax> inputNo=102 ; printf -v inputNo "%02d" $inputNo ; echo $inputNo
102
```

You'll want to make sure it's numeric first otherwise the conversion will fail. If you want to be able to pad *any* string out to two or more characters, you can also use:

```
while [[ ${#inputNo} -lt 2 ]] ; do
    inputNo="0${inputNo}"
done
```

which is basically a `while` loop that prefixes your string with "0" until the length is greater than or equal to two.

Note that this can also be done in `bash` by prefixing the number with two zeroes then simply getting the last two characters of that string, checking first that it's not already at least the desired size:

```
if [[ ${#inputNo} -lt 2 ]] ; then
    inputNo="00${inputNo}"
    inputNo="${inputNo: -2}"
fi
```

The difference is probably not too great for a two-digit number but you may find the latter solution is better if you need larger widths.

---

If you're using a shell *other* than `bash` (unlikely, based on your tags), you'll need to find the equivalents, or revert to using external processes to do the work, something like:

```
while [[ $(echo -n ${inputNo} | wc -c) -lt 2 ]] ; do
    inputNo="0${inputNo}"
done
```

This does basically what you were thinking off in your question but note the use of `-n` in the `echo` command to prevent the trailing newline (which was almost certainly causing your off-by-one error).

But, as stated, this is a fall-back position. If you're using `bash`, the earlier suggestions of mine are probably best.

Comment: No need for external processes in the general case: `while test "${#inputNo}" -lt 2; do inputNo="0$inputNo"; done` (*[[* changed to *test* with added quoting to make it compatible with more shells).

Comment: No need for bash extensions (${#...}) either: `case $inputNo in [0-9]) inputNo="0$inputNo";;*);;esac`.

Comment: ${#…} is not really bash-specific. It is part of the POSIX shell spec (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02), though it is not present in the authentic Bourne shell (http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html#5).

Comment: If you're using inputNo mathematically keep in mind that after it's formatted the shell will think the single digit numbers with leading 0's are octal.  Also, the 2nd var in printf is assigned to the 1st var i.e. $inputNo -> inputNo. Obvious, but for us newbies...

Answer (score 9):

**For general-purpose padding whether the string is numeric or not**

No need for piping `echo` into `wc` or using a `while` loop.

In Bash, you can get the length of a string like this: `${#inputNo}`.

And since you can do substrings, you can do this instead:

```
if [[ ${#input} < 2 ]] 
then
    inputNo="00${inputNo}"
    inputNo="${inputNo: -2}"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/commands/builtin/printf, an example from there:

```
the_mac="0:13:ce:7:7a:ad"

# lowercase hex digits
the_mac="$(printf "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x" 0x${the_mac//:/ 0x})"

# or the uppercase-digits variant
the_mac="$(printf "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X" 0x${the_mac//:/ 0x})"
```